# React redux form update pristine after change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I need to make dispatch and change the form data after page loaded:

`dispatch(change("project", field, value));`

however this will change "pristine" to false and "dirty" to true, anyone has a good solution for such case?

Answer (score 4):

In order to achieve this, you can provide `initialValues` to decorated with reduxForm component:

```
compose(
  connect((state) => ({
    initialValues: state.someData
  })),
  reduxForm({
    form: 'someForm'
  })
)(Component)
```

Or, alternatively, you can use `initialize` action creator from `redux-form` after data will be loaded from server:

```
dispatch(initialize('myForm', newInitialValues));
```

Dispatching `initialize` action will set state of your form to `pristine`

Comment: nope, already have initialValues as my first api runs, then run second api and use change(... to update some of the field in initialValue, and in my component I run iniialize( again, but pristine still change to false.

Comment: @maxli can you try to run `initialize` with new values without dispatching `change` action?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the correct way, but it is working for me.

```
this.props.dispatch({type: '@@redux-form/BLUR', payload: yourPayload, meta: {form: "formName", field: "formField", touch: true}});
```

I dispatch the code above, at the onChange event of my field, forcing the redux-form to update the pristine status.

Comment: Hello I have am doing that as well but it doesn't seem to be working. Also on change. Any thoughts?

Answer (score -2):

You can set the silent flag to true, this will not update pristine and dirty flags.
Example: `actions.change(model, value, { silent: true })`
You could also use `actions.load()`.
Difference between `load()` and `change()`

> This is different than calling actions.change(model, value, { silent: true }). Both are similar with one main difference: actions.load also updates the .loadedValue, whereas a silent change does not.

https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/api/actions.html#actions-load

Comment: So this only applies to the older [react-Redux-Form](https://github.com/davidkpiano/react-redux-form)  that is in maintenance mode now and had its last version in 2017.  This functionality doesn't appear to be in the more active [Redux-Form](https://github.com/redux-form/redux-form) project.